# How to create an interface method which accepts implementations of an interface as parameters

Tags: c#, interface

I'm creating an collision handler interface for a game project. I am trying to get the implemented class to accept sub-interfaces of IGameObject.

I've tried using IGameObject, which has sub interfaces IEnemy, IPlayer, etc.

```
interface ICollisionHandler
{
    void HandleCollision(IGameObject object1, IGameObject object2);
}

class GenericCollision: ICollisionHandler
{
    public void HandleCollision(IGameObject foo, IEnemy bar)
    {
        bar.TakeDamage();            
    }
}
```

GenericCollision should accept IEnemy since it is a sub-interface of IGameObject, but this makes it so that ICollisionHandler is not implemented. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use generics and do something like this.

```
interface ICollisionHandler<T>
    where T : IGameObject
{
    void HandleCollision(IGameObject object1, T object2);
}

class GenericCollision: ICollisionHandler<IEnemy>
{
    public void HandleCollision(IGameObject foo, IEnemy bar)
    {
        bar.TakeDamage();            
    }
}
```

This allows the implementation to use any sub-interface of `IGameObject`.

You're encouraged to use a better name than `T` as a type parameter for the generics but I'm not familiar enough with what you're doing to come up with one.

Comment: That's absolutly no difference to changing the second parameter Type of the Interface to IEnemy.
If the two functions shall match, we have to change one or the other; there's no work around.

Comment: @Holger In that limited example indeed, but OP wants to implement the `ICollisionHandler` interface for `IPlayer` and other sub-interfaces of `IGameObject`, not only `IEnemy`.

Comment: Yes, but there is no ICollisionHandler Interface. With templates you create several interfaces, one for each type. You end up with `GenericCollision : ICollisionHandler<IEnemy>, ICollsionHandler<IPlayer>` and that's usually not what you call generic.

Comment: That's certainly a valid concern. Depending on the usage of this, making the interface `ICollisionHandler<in T>` can make it a bit more useful.